# If $f$ is differentiable for any value except $x=0$, and $e^{f(x)} = x$, show that $f’(x) = 1/x$

Tags: derivatives

If $f$ is differentiable for any value except $x=0$, and $e^{f(x)} = x$, show that $f’(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: Differentiate both sides of $e^{f(x)} = x$? Use the Chain Rule?

Comment: Can you guess why I’m voting to close your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that $e^{f(x)}=x$, we can take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\begin{align*} \dfrac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)}&=\dfrac{d}{dx}x\\f'(x)e^{f(x)}&=1\\f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{e^{f(x)}}&=\dfrac 1x \end{align*} $$

Note: there exists no function $f$ that satisfies $e^{f(x)}=x$ when $x$ is not positive. This is because exponentials are strictly positive functions; this was perhaps a mistake in the problem statement?

Answer (score 2):

As explained by doobdood, we need $x>0$ in order to make sense of $e^{f(x)} = x$.
Thus, by taking the natural logarithm:
$$f(x) = \log x$$
And by taking the derivative of both sides (for $x \ne 0$):
$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I really like this answer because it showcases a technique that is often left to the wayside. Sadly I must refrain from upvoting it because I don’t reward people who encourage users to abuse the site.